# I have a function that prints input parameters for a calculation. How to return a text string so that it can be saved as text file as well?

Tags: python, string, numpy, text

I would like to summarize the input parameters for a python calculation using text strings. I can summarize the input parameters using `print()` but I don't know how to also save these as text strings.

**Sample Code**

First, define the scan of input parameters:

```
import numpy as np

gapsize = np.arange(0.5,0.8,0.1)
ringwidth = np.arange(1.25,5,0.75)
outputangle = [28.43]
```

Now define a function that prints a parameter-specific summary of these values

```
def printSCANvalues(parameter):
    ## Do cases for text descriptions
    if parameter is ringwidth:
        paramTEXT = "RW"
    elif parameter is gapsize:
        paramTEXT = "Gap"
    elif parameter is outputangle:
        paramTEXT = "Facet Angle"

    if parameter is ringwidth or parameter is gapsize:
        unit = 'um'
    elif parameter is outputangle:
        unit = 'deg.'


    ## only calculate the gradient for arrays with more than one value
    if len(parameter) > 1:
        step = round(1000*np.gradient(parameter)[0])/1000
    elif len(parameter) == 1:
        step = 0

    stopVAL = round(1000*parameter[-1])/1000


    print("")
    print(paramTEXT, "Scan: qty =", len(parameter),", start = ", parameter[0],
          unit, ", stop = ", stopVAL, unit, ", step = ", step, unit)
    print(paramTEXT, "values: ", parameter, unit)
```

Now use function to generate the text that summarizes the input parameter scan:

```
print("")
print("====== Input Parameter Scan Values ======")
print("")

printSCANvalues(ringwidth)
printSCANvalues(gapsize)
printSCANvalues(outputangle)
```

Screenshot of output:

[image: screenshot of output]

**The problem**

I would also like to save this output as a text string so that it can be written to a text file.  Is there a way to save the associated string for each parameter type before `print()` is executed so that I can use it later?

Comment: The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) for the `print()` function indicates it accepts an optional *`file`* keyword argument — which implies that anything you can print can be sent to an (open) file. You can also do it using the [`contextlib.redirect_stdout()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.redirect_stdout) function.

Answer (score 0):

As a very general rule, in a situation like this, you shouldn't have the function do the printing.  Have the function return a string, and let the caller decide what to DO with the string.  Like this.  You can see how to take the results and copy them to a file later.

```
def SCANvalues(parameter):
    ## Do cases for text descriptions
    if parameter is ringwidth:
        paramTEXT = "RW"
    elif parameter is gapsize:
        paramTEXT = "Gap"
    elif parameter is outputangle:
        paramTEXT = "Facet Angle"

    if parameter is ringwidth or parameter is gapsize:
        unit = 'um'
    elif parameter is outputangle:
        unit = 'deg.'

    ## only calculate the gradient for arrays with more than one value
    step = 0
    if len(parameter) > 1:
        step = round(1000*np.gradient(parameter)[0])/1000

    stopVAL = round(1000*parameter[-1])/1000

    s =  f"{paramTEXT} Scan: qty = {len(parameter)}, start = {parameter[0]}, stop = {stopVal} {unit}, step = {step} {unit}\n"
    s += f"{paramTEXT} Values: {parameter} {unit}"
    return s

print("")
print("====== Input Parameter Scan Values ======")
print("")

rw = SCANvalues(ringwidth)
gs = SCANvalues(gapsize)
oa = SCANvalues(outputangle)
print(rw)
print(gs)
print(oa)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  This doesn't appear to generate a string variable as far as I can tell.  's' never shows up in the variable explorer.  I may be missing something obvious since I'm new to python.  Also, maybe there's a way to append "RW" etc to "s" for each variable type?

Comment: ??? The last three lines of the function generate a string `s` and return that string.  The mainline code just prints the string, but of course you can store it in your own variable and do what you like.  I don't know what you mean by "RW".

Comment: Hi Tim, I guess the question was "how do I store it as a variable"?  I realize it's generating a string I just don't know how to use it afterward.  "RW" is my designation for one of the parameters.  I was just trying to distinguish the different copies of 's' that would be generated.

Comment: You're not thinking about what you're asking.  If you call `"abc".upper()`, how do you store its result in a variable?  It's the same thing here.  They're just functions.  You store it in a variable by assigning its result to a variable.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out using the tip from @martineau and the modification from  @Tim Roberts.

```
def SCANvalues(parameter):
    ## Do cases for text descriptions
    if parameter is ringwidth:
        paramTEXT = "RW"
    elif parameter is gapsize:
        paramTEXT = "Gap"
    elif parameter is outputangle:
        paramTEXT = "Facet Angle"

    if parameter is ringwidth or parameter is gapsize:
        unit = 'um'
    elif parameter is outputangle:
        unit = 'deg.'

    ## only calculate the gradient for arrays with more than one value
    step = 0
    if len(parameter) > 1:
        step = round(1000*np.gradient(parameter)[0])/1000

    stopVAL = round(1000*parameter[-1])/1000

    
    s =  f"{paramTEXT} Scan: qty = {len(parameter)}, start = {parameter[0]}, stop = {stopVAL} {unit}, step = {step} {unit}\n"
    s += f"{paramTEXT} Values: {parameter} {unit}\n"
    return s
```

## Code for printing to a file

I didn't see if there was an option to print to a file as well as the console so I just included two instances

```
log = open('log.txt', 'w')
geos = [ringwidth, gapsize, outputangle]

def geoPRINT(geoPARAMS):
    print("\n ====== Input Parameter Scan Values ======\n")
    print("\n ====== Input Parameter Scan Values ======\n",file = log)
    for i in range(len(geoPARAMS)):
        print(SCANvalues(geoPARAMS[i]))
        print(SCANvalues(geoPARAMS[i]),file = log)

    
geoPRINT(geos)
log.close()
```